# error: undefined reference to `sched_setaffinity' on windows xp

Tags: multithreading, windows-xp, pthreads, affinity

Basically the code below was intended for use on linux and maybe thats the reason I get the error because I'm using windows XP, but I figure that pthreads should work just as well on both machines. I'm using gcc as my compiler and I did link with -lpthread but I got the following error anyways.

|21|undefined reference to `sched_setaffinity'|
|30|undefined reference to`sched_setaffinity'|

If there is another method to setting the thread affinity using pthreads (on windows) let me know. I already know all about the windows.h thread affinity functions available but I want to keep things multiplatform. thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sched.h>

double waste_time(long n)
{
    double res = 0;
    long i = 0;
    while(i <n * 200000)
    {
        i++;
        res += sqrt (i);
    }
    return res;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned long mask = 1; /* processor 0 */

/* bind process to processor 0 */
    if (sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(mask), &mask) <0)//line 21
    {
        perror("sched_setaffinity");
    }

/* waste some time so the work is visible with "top" */
    printf ("result: %f\n", waste_time (2000));

    mask = 2; /* process switches to processor 1 now */
    if (sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(mask), &mask) <0)//line 30
    {
        perror("sched_setaffinity");
    }

/* waste some more time to see the processor switch */
    printf ("result: %f\n", waste_time (2000));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sched_getaffinity()` and `sched_setaffinity()` are strictly Linux-specific calls. Windows provides its own set of specific Win32 API calls that affect scheduling. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13145211/1374437) for sample code for Windows.

Comment: This is just one more reason I hate Microsoft. Now I'm forced to use two different api's. Do you know if there is any reason why pthreads weren't allowed to set the affinity on Windows?

Comment: I don't see any reference to Pthreads in your code. The `sched_*` family of calls are not part of Pthreads - they are low-level Linux system calls that provide hints to the scheduler. As Pthreads is not the native threading API on Windows, one could expect that it is not fully implementated. Which implementation do you use?

Comment: I just used the pthreads header which comes with mingw/gcc. I used codeblocks and the mingw that came with it actually. Are there other apis that are multiplatform (linux/windows) that can set thread affinity?

Comment: Yes, there is: the [hwloc](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/) subproject of Open MPI. It does much more than affinity setting though (e.g. topology enumeration).

Comment: Thanks, it looks interesting.