# Externally called OpenMP program runs with only one thread if called by another OpenMP program

Tags: c++, c, linux, process, openmp

I have two programs A and B, which were compiled with g++-5.1 and openmp.
The code is running inside Scientific Linux 7.1.

```
g++ <program>.cpp -fopenmp -o <program>
```

Program (A) starts program (B) with a std::system call.
The call graph of the programs looks like this:

```
|- A
   |- B
```

Program B should use all available CPU cores on the system, but it utilizes just one thread.
If program A is compiled without the `-fopenmp` flag than program B uses all available cores.

Even if program B is not a child process of A anymore (`std::system("setsid ./B &")`) it just uses one thread. Call graph:

```
|- B
...
|- A
```

Why does this behavior happen and how can I get program B to utilize all cores when called by program A?

Again the weird part is that I get the expected behavior if the caller is not compiled with -fopenmp. Other things that I've tried: spawning the child process with execve, posix_spawn, having a bash instance inbetween. The problems also occurs by using the compiler g++-4.8.3. I am out of ideas.

Program A: A.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
        std::system("setsid ./B  100000000000 &");
}
```

Program B: B.cpp

```
#include "omp.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

// ignore the workload, I just need something to spin the CPU
double workload(size_t num_steps)
{
   size_t i;
   double  x=0;
   double sum = 0.0;
   double step = 1.0 / (double) num_steps;
   #pragma omp parallel private(i,x)
   {
      #pragma omp for reduction(+:sum) schedule(dynamic, 100)
      for (i=0; i<num_steps; i=i+1){
         x=(i+0.5)*step;
         sum = sum + 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
      }
   }
   return step*sum;
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
   size_t a = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 10);
   std::cout << a << " " << workload(a) << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try with `std::system("cat /proc/self/status");` instead and look at the value of `Cpus_allowed_list`. Maybe thread pinning is enabled. Check for presence of `OMP_PROC_BIND`, `OMP_PLACES` or `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` in the set of environment variables.

Comment: @HristoIliev thanks a lot for this hint. Cpus_allowed_list = 1, OMP_PROC_BIND=TRUE and OMP_PLACES, and GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY are not set. OMP_PROC_BIND=FALSE kind of seems to solve the problem. But now we have call program (A) like this OMP_PROC_BIND=FALSE ./A. Is there a way to set it during runtime?

Comment: Do not set `OMP_PROC_BIND` when running A. Use `setenv(3)` to set `OMP_PROC_BIND` to `TRUE` from within A before spawning B or use `execle(2)`/`execvpe(2)` to pass a modified environment to the child process.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks a lot. This works. Unfortunately I can not flag your comment as the answer. Can you think of anyway how to avoid writing a wrapper script for tool A to unset OMP_PROC_BIND?

Comment: There you go - I've summarised in an answer several ways to do it without juggling with the environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialisation of most OpenMP runtime libraries happens in their constructors, which get executed very early in the process lifetime. Hence, it is not possible to prevent the binding effect of `OMP_PROC_BIND` on program A, but one could counteract it before spawning program B. There are multiple ways, but two come immediately to my mind:

1) Use `taskset` in the call to `std::system()` to override the CPU affinity mask of the child process:

```
std::system("taskset -c 0-63 ./B 100000000000");
```

The `-c 0-63` parameter produces a CPU affinity mask with 64 bits set, which should be good for most current generation multicore systems (unless the program runs on Intel Xeon Phi or on some exotic hardware like our Bull Coherent Switch coupled fat nodes). Obviously, it won't work if `taskset` is not installed on the system (being part of `util-linux`, it should be installed by default on many systems).

2) Use `sched_setaffinity(2)` or `pthread_setaffinity_np(3)` to reset the CPU affinity mask of A before calling `std::system()`. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13145211/1374437) for inspiration.

3) If you can afford external dependencies, the [hwloc library](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/) has a very nice API that can be used to obtain and manipulate the CPU affinity. It is also cross-platform and will also work on Windows.

Option 3 is the most clean one as you don't have to hardcode in advance a wide enough mask in the parameter to `taskset` or in the CPU set passed to the scheduler functions.